# Convexity of the modulus of convexity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

The book "Geometric Properties of Banach Spaces and Nonlinear Iterations" by Charles Chidume (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-84882-190-3) says (page 7)

"We now present the following known and interesting theorem. A proof can be found in Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri, [312].

Theorem 1.13. The modulus of convexity of a normed space $X$, $\delta_X$, is a convex and continuous function."

However Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's book "Classical Banach Spaces, vol. 2" (page 67) says "The modulus of convexity of a Banach space need not be itself a convex function."

So it seems that Chidume's book is incorrect, but it seems like a very major error. Can anyone sheed some light on the situation?

Comment: Does the book by Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri has a counterexample? Have you tried to compute the modulus of convexity for some simple norms?

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus_and_characteristic_of_convexity#Properties

Comment: Wikipedia just references Lindenstrauss and Tzafriri's book. The book says that counterexamples are in Liokoumovich 1973 article  "The existence of B-spaces with non-convex modulus of convexity" which is in Russian.

Comment: Basically I am looking for an expert to clarify whether Chidume's statement is correct in some special setting, or whether it is just completely wrong

Answer (score 1):

The example by Liokoumovich is mentioned also in the paper by J. Banas and K. Fraczek, 'Deformation of Banach spaces', Comment. Math. Univ. Carolin. 34,1 (1993), 47-53.

You can obtain its ball as a (nontrivial) intersection of a rectangle with a circle in the plane. More precisely, take any $\lambda > 1$ and define $${\|(x,y)\|}_\lambda = \max \left\{ \lambda |x|, \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right\}.$$

More details can be found in the aforementioned paper.

Concerning your other comment, I would bet that the modulus of convexity is indeed convex for most, if not all, classical spaces (it is so in the case of $\ell_p$ spaces, $1\leq p \leq \infty$).